# Model.findByIdAndRemove() no longer accepts a callback

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

When I check the checkbox on my to do list I get an error that say "Model.findByIdAndRemove() no longer accepts a callback".

I am trying to make it so that when an item is checked it is removed from my to do list.

```
app.post("/delete", function (req, res) {
  const checkedItemId = req.body.checkbox;
  Item.findByIdAndRemove(checkedItemId, function (err) {
    if (!err) {
      console.log("Successfully deleted checked item");
      res.redirect("/");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily rolsolved by using `async/await` pattern, and `findByIdAndDelete` method like so:

```js
app.post("/delete", async (req, res) => { //< Note the use of async and arrow function
   try { //< Use a try/catch block for cleaner error handling
      const checkedItemId = req.body.checkbox;
      const deletedItem = await Item.findByIdAndDelete(checkedItemId); //< Note the use of await keyword
      console.log("Successfully deleted checked item:", deletedItem);
      res.redirect("/");
   } catch(err){
      console.log('Error:', err);
      //Send error message to front-end
   }
});
```

The `findByIdAndDelete` method fires the `findOneAndDelete` middleware, which has a useful number of options. See [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.findByIdAndDelete()) for the docs.